# State of a system at previous time

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, schroedinger-equation, hamiltonian, time-evolution

If I am given the state of a quantum system at $t=0$ as $| \psi \rangle$ and I know the Hamiltonian $H$ of the system for time $t<0$, how can I write the state of the system at some time $t<0$?

Answer (score 2):

Well, assuming the Hamiltonian is time independent, the rule

$$|\psi(t)\rangle = e^{-iH(t-t_0)}|\psi(t_0)\rangle$$

is always true, it doesn't matter which time comes first. Just let $t_0=0$ and you have your state for any $t$ you want. Alternatively, you can solve the Schrödinger equation using the $t<0$ Hamiltonian and use the $t=0$ state as your "initial" condition. Despite the name, the initial condition doesn't have to be at some initial time.

Comment: What about the Heisenberg picture? How would an operator at $t<0$ be written? Also, if backward time evolution is that trivial, why is there so much fuss about time reversal symmetry and the time reversal operator?

Comment: @NamanAgarwal The same reasoning applies in the Heisenberg picture. Just take all the usual formulas and plug in whatever time you want and whatever initial condition you want. While I'm not 100% sure about this,  I think the idea behind T-symmetry is not that you can look backwards in time (which you can), but that the backward evolution should also be a valid forward evolution, and this is nontrivial.